# How to add half star to rating control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to add half star to rating control
I tried this: `HalfStarCssClass="HalfFilledStar"`
and put the image in style `"HalfFilledStar"` as I did with filled star and waiting star and empty star and it didn't success:

```
cc1:Rating ID="AddRate" CurrentRating="0" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="AddRate_Changed" StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                  HalfStarCssClass="HalfFilledStar"       FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" runat="server">
                                    /cc1:Rating>
```

And this's the styles:

```
 '.Star
    {
        background-image: url(images/Star.png);
        height: 28px;
        width: 29px;
    }


    .WaitingStar
    {
        background-image: url(images/WaitingStar.png);
        height: 28px;
        width: 29px;
    }


    .FilledStar
    {
        background-image: url(images/FilledStar.png);
        height: 28px;
        width: 29px;
    }

     .HalfFilledStar
    {
        background-image: url(images/HalfFilledStar.png);
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
    }'
```

Comment: ajax rating control does not support half stars, you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/459004/How-can-I-apply-the-half-star-rating-control-with#answer2